# Delphi, RTTI, Master-detail Class

Tags: delphi, master-detail, rtti

I'm trying to do a framework using RTTI. But I can't figure out how to do the load from a master-detail.

For example, like this:

```
[HasMany('ID_CLIENTE')]
property Endereco: TObjectList<TEndereco> read FEndereco write FEndereco;
```

[image: screenshot]

I have a class that feeds the property directly from a DB, but I don't know how I can feed the property's master-detail.

Comment: This is a weird question, because you're trying to do something Advanced but it doesn't explain enough for anyone to know why you are stuck.   It's terrible to put a screenshot of code, for one thing. For another, something as large a subject as one to many relationships, we can not guess what your framework does or how it works.  Writing your framework for you is not on topic here.

Comment: Sorry, It's my first topic here.

Comment: I have a generic class responsible to set a value on runtime to the propertys class, directly from DB, using attributes. 
With primitive types its ok, but when the property is TObjectList (master-detail) I can't, case in runtime i dont know how figure out what kind is that object, to do a cast.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I think your problem is you actually have even more problems than that.   I suggest you should study existing ORMs, and you might learn techniques. I suspect your entire design is broken, and unworkable.  Go study MORMOT for a while.  http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki/Synopse+OpenSource

Comment: I will.
But why u suspect my entire design is broken, and unworkable?

Comment: Because designing an ORM is hard.  It's cute that you're trying. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. 
But now, I have a only question. It's possible create a Object Generic List,
of the type of the current class, in runtime (using RTTI)?
If someone can answer it, it's a great start.

Comment: It is really simple, you walk the objectlist, treat each list object as TObject and hydrate it recursively?

Comment: Thanks for the answer whosrdaddy, I will try to be clearer. 
I have a class that has a property TObjectList<TAddress>, for example.
Now I want a function, using RTTI, that returns a TObjectList<T>, but in this return, <T> should be of the type "TAddress" in this case.

function TClient.GetAddress: TObjectList<TAddres>;
begin
  if not assigned(result) then
    result := functionGenericRTTIthatReturnListCreate<TAddress>(codeFK);
end;

Comment: You can create any class instance at runtime, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068775/how-to-create-an-instance-of-object-with-rtti-in-delphi-2010) for more info. The point is that your ORM object hydration logic should be as generic as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot whosrdaddy !
The link you passed me is exactly what i was looking for.